# Display data from state

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have took data from firebase and want to display:

```
class DisplayVisit extends Component{
    state = {
        allVisit: [] //this I have changed        
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getVisit();
    }

    getVisit = async() => {
        try {
            
           const currentVisit = await doctorvisit.get();
           this.setState({ allVisit: currentVisit })

           this.state.allVisit.forEach(element => {
               console.log(element.data()) // i see data, fields like => {user, info, visitAt}
          });
            
        } catch(error) {
            console.log('error getting visits ', error);           
        }
    }    

    render(){

        return(
            {Object.keys(this.state.allVisit).map(key => (
                <span>{this.state.allVisit[key].info}1</span>                                 
             ))}
        )   
    }
}
```

But nothing is render.

I tried also `{key.info}` but nothing is render.

Screen from console:
[image]

Log from `console.log(this.state.allVisit);`:
[image]

Comment: Hello! Do you get any error in console?

Comment: when I run this `this.state.allVisit.forEach(element => {
            console.log(element.data()) // i see data, fields like => {user, info, visitAt}
       });` I see data. I just need to loop them into `render`

Comment: scren for what you get from console.log(element.data())

Comment: I have uploaded to the question screen from console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it based on Google docs:

```
class DisplayVisit extends Component{
    state = {
        allVisit: [] 
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getVisit();
    }

      getVisit = async() => {
        try {            
            await doctorvisit.get().then(querySnapshot => {
               const data = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
               
               this.setState({allVisit : data});
           })            
        } catch(error) {
            console.log('error getting visits ', error);           
        }
    }
}
```

**Documentation**:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?hl=en

and **blog/post:**

https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage

Comment: can you add the documentation that you followed?

Answer (score 1):

If i see good, you're setting the state allVisit to currentVisit, wich is a single object.

Either your allVisit property in state is an array with visit objects inside, or simply apply currentVisit in state as a single object.

In the meantime, you're looping a single object, if its what you're trying to achieve, remove the .info after the [key] and you will have all you're property displayed

If you want to loop through nested objects or an array of object provide more informations

[image: result]

Update, i'll tried to guess your data so try with this code

```
export default class DisplayVisit extends Component {
  state = {
    allVisit: [] //this I have changed
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getVisit();
  }

  getVisit = async () => {
    try {
      const { docs } = await doctorvisit.get();
      
       //try this if first not working
      const allVisitsData = await doctor.visit.get()
 
      
      this.setState({ allVisit: docs });

      //try this if first not working
      //this.setState({ allVisit: allVisitData.docs });
      //or this

    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error getting visits ", error);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.allVisit.map((visit) => (
          <span key={visit.info}>{visit.info} 1</span>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: when run this `{Object.keys(this.state.allVisit).map((key) => (
                                    <p>{this.state.allVisit[key]}</p>
                                ))}` I got error = `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {S_, D_, bf, metadata, query}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: could you please log your state object after    this.setState({ allVisit: currentVisit }) and currentVisit please

Comment: I see that the one problem is here stete = `{ allVisit: {} }`.....so I change this to `allVisit: []`

Comment: Yes it makes more sense, allVisit should be an array of visit, if it's an array you could go just with a .map(), otherwise, if you have a CurrentVisit state property with nested visit object you need to go with object.keys. let me know how it goes

Comment: when did as you asked `console.log(this.props.allVisit);`  into console I have `undefined`....so setState is wrong, but why?

Comment: This.state.allVisit, but log here what this.state returns

Comment: ah sorry my mistake...I will uploaded the image

Comment: Please log in comment the payload from const currentVisit = await doctorvisit.get(); in code field so i can see deeply the structure of your payload

Comment: Check the updated answer and validate if works please

Comment: `const { data } = await doctorvisit.get();` = data is undefined

Comment: `this.setState({ allVisit3: currentVisit.data() });` = error getting visits  TypeError: currentVisit.data is not a functi

Comment: I will also try also some combination and will let you know

Comment: i''ve upadted the code, could you please log in case it's not, what is in the docs array ? (with a object opened to see clear)